# How to get bitcoin wallet name from bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli

In http://bitcoinwhoswho.com/ , we can find wallet name from bitcoin address, how do they do so? Is there any signature of wallet name in bitcoin address or in transaction id?

Comment: There's no concept of a "Wallet" on the blockchain. The "Wallet" you are using with your Bitcoin software is just a group of keys.

Comment: yep, thats why that website puzzled me. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE!

I have had a quick look at the website you referenced specifically, however, it suggests most of the information that they have is because people have 'claimed' their address and provided the details.

If you have a look at [this example](http://bitcoinwhoswho.com/address/1JLebfncFopw6jAgLr6EnBndtSLzMd5Nfc), that represents just about all that is publicly obtainable when someone makes a transaction + the public keys. And, website information, names and, labels is not sourced from the blockchain.